# Data From Database display to textbox after text change event c#

Tags: c#, database

How do I make an c# application with a database where I store values in database eg let's say string (CName)"xr" = (Description)"Go to sleep" and string (CName)"vs" = (Description)"at 10 pm" and these values will be stored and when I type "xr vs" in a textbox the string "Go to sleep at 10 pm" will be displayed on another texbox in a form. Please help I'm new to programming

```
{
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-EU4PTNQ;Initial Catalog=Medrive;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
            {
                con.Open();
                if (bunifuTextBox2.Text != "")
                {

                    string DescriptionQueryStr = "Select CName from Ciphers";
                    string[] tbVals = bunifuTextBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DescriptionQueryStr, con))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i > tbVals.Length; i++)
                        {
                            DescriptionQueryStr += " where Description=@Description" + i.ToString() + " OR ";
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbVals[i];

                        }
                        //Strip off the last OR
                        DescriptionQueryStr = DescriptionQueryStr.Substring(0, DescriptionQueryStr.Length - 2);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                        {

                            using (SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (da.Read())
                                {
                                    var hasAnotherRecord = true;
                                    while (hasAnotherRecord)
                                    {
                                        sb.AppendLine(da.GetValue(0).ToString());
                                        hasAnotherRecord = da.Read();
                                        if (hasAnotherRecord)
                                            sb.Append(" ");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                           
                        }

                        TAbunifuTextBox10.Text = sb.ToString();

                    }
                  
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: There could be some improvements done, but what isnt working?

Comment: When I try to write "vs" in the textbox after writing "xr" the string "at 10 pm" is not showing in the other textbox

Comment: Are you getting inside the `while` loop?

Comment: No I'm not , when I type "xr" in the first textbox "Go to sleep" will appear in the second textbox but when I type "vs" in front of "xr" the string "at 10 pm" is not being retrieved from database

Comment: That's where I want help , please.

Comment: do you have a `Description` with value of `vsxr` in the `Ciphers` table? If not, then that's why nothing is returned. I suspect this is a query issue and or data issue in your database.

Comment: I don't have one , is there a way I can type xrvs in one textbox when I have CName "vs" and CName "xr" and then join the two strings, like to append ???

Comment: Maybe you should use `+=` instead of  `=`. Here `TAbunifuTextBox10.Text += da.GetValue(0).ToString();`

Comment: @tapiwa sure there is. You can do a like statement, create a function in sql that would return the format you want etc.

Comment: Or you can split the string from the textbox and include both 'xr' and 'vs' as criteria.   'Select CName from Ciphers where Description= Description1 OR Description= Description2'.  You will need to split the string and then create a loop for each result from the split and build up the query.

Comment: How do I do that , I'm kinda new to programming ,can I an example please

Comment: @tapiwa Here check out this fiddle which does most of it: https://dotnetfiddle.net/XRi6MZ

Comment: @Admin Alright ,thank you let me try it out

Comment: @Adam i'm still failing to make it work. how do i use this method while using database

Comment: I added an answer, you probably need to tweak it a bit.

Comment: @Adam where can i get this answer from??

Comment: i am failing to understand how to use sql with  the code on this link  dotnetfiddle.net/XRi6MZ , help

Comment: @tapiwa, I added an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63272228/1821368

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work...

```
private void bunifuTextBox2_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-EU4PTNQ;Initial Catalog=Medrive;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=True;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"))
    {
        con.Open();
        if (bunifuTextBox2.Text != "")
        {
            using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(DescriptionQueryStr , con))
            {   
                string DescriptionQueryStr = "Select CName from Ciphers";
                string[] tbVals = bunifuTextBox2.Text.Split(new string[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for(int i = 0; i < tbVals.Length; i++)
                {
                    DescriptionQueryStr += " where Description=@Description"+i.ToString() + " OR ";
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description" + i.ToString(), SqlDbType.String).Value = tbVals[i];
                }
                //Strip off the last OR
                DescriptionQueryStr = DescriptionQueryStr.Substring(0, DescriptionQueryStr.Length - 2);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    
                using(SqlDataReader da = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    if (da.Read())
                    {
                        var hasAnotherRecord = true;
                        while (hasAnotherRecord)
                        {
                            sb.AppendLine(da.GetValue(0).ToString());
                            hasAnotherRecord = da.Read();
                            if (hasAnotherRecord)
                                sb.Append(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            TAbunifuTextBox10.Text = sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Also, as Alexander pointed out below, you should dispose of the SqlDataReader class(and any IDispoable class, in general).  This is ensured by the wrapping class in a using block, which I added.
Antonín also had some good points which are addressed.

Comment: You must release resources. Use `using` or `Dispose`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov definitely agree, but to be honest isn't the OP issue and without the changes doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: Good point and important to illustrate and discuss, I wrapped in a using block

Comment: @Adam  the code is now returning the last record in database. i just wanted code lets say i type "man" in  textbox bunifuTextBox2 a phrase like "This is a man" will be displayed in textboxTAbunifuTextBox10. String "woman" will have description "this is a woman". Then when i type "man woman" in bunifuTextBox2 the 2 phrases "This is a man" and "this is a woman" will be joined together showing in TAbunifuTextBox10 as "This is a man this is a woman". Its like creating shortcuts for long phrases and be able to join them

Comment: @Adam ,How to create stored string shortcuts that represent phrases when typed on a textbox

Comment: I updated the answer to append each returned record, separated by a space.

Comment: Appending string in a loop is a bad thing, please use `StringBuilder`. Always. `AddWithValue` is a bad habit. `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` are disposable too. And btw the `DescriptionQueryStr` would be invalid for multiple `tbVals`.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek Good points.  I updated the answer to address all except I do not see an issue with the query string when tbVals length is > 1, can you elaborate?

Comment: @Adam thank you for your response.I am having errors at **cmd.Parameters.Add** since cmd is declared after that line. Also **reader.Read()** is giving an error as it states that reader is not avalable. when i tried to tweak the code a bit the all values are being displayed so do the connection needs closing???

Comment: @Adam its returning everything in the database even when i dont type something corresponding the that record this is what i did

Comment: @tapiwa, I updated the answer to fix the typo and where SqlCommand is declared but sounds like you figured these edits out.  You don't need to close the connection, it is closed in the Dispose method, which is executed when the using block is exited.  It is my understanding you close the connection if you want to reuse it and dispose of it otherwise.

Comment: @Adam i edited the code above , see what i have done but its not working yet

Comment: @ Adam thank you, what about the *reader.Read() part* reader is giving an error

Comment: @Adam the code is returning everything in the table even when i type something that represents one record???

Comment: @Adam even if i type any string in textbox that isn't in the database its now giving the everything, Maybe **DescriptionQueryStr** part

Comment: You can get something like `Select CName from Ciphers where Description=@Description0 OR  where Description=@Description1 O`. You can have only one `where` for the `select`.

Comment: @Adam isnt it the part we are declaring `(DescriptionQueryStr, con)` since `DescriptionQueryStr` only has `select from CName` but  doesnt have `where` part??

Comment: @Adam the code is not giving out what i wrote in textbox (even when i write something not under CName), its giving out every record under **Description**

Comment: @AntonínLejsek the code is not giving out what i wrote in textbox (even when i write something not under CName), its giving out every record under **Description**